# Pythonのスクリプトをapp・exe形式にしたい。

Tags: python, python3, anaconda, anaconda3, cx-freeze

### 環境

mac os high sierraを使用しており
anacondaのそれぞれの仮装環境下のpipでパッケージ等をインストールしながら開発しています。
cx_Freeze等のパッケージはpipでインストールしています。
仮装環境内のPythonのバージョンはPython 3.7.3です。
cx_Freezeは6.5.3です。

### やりたい事

cx_Freezeというパッケージを使用するとPythonファイルをapp・exe化出来ると聞いたのでpipインストールを行いドキュメントに従いsetup.pyを書いてスクリプトが置いてあるフォルダで実行しました。
下記のエラーが出力されてbuildフォルダは生成されたのですが、appファイルを実行してもプログラムが実行されないです。
pyinstaller等を使う方法も取れますが、生成されたアプリの起動が遅いと聞くのでcx_Freezeを使用したいです。

[How to write setup.py including own python module and HTML CSS files?](https://github.com/marcelotduarte/cx_Freeze/issues/916)

開発者の方とやり取りしているのですが、anaconda に詳しくないため、よく分からないという状況です。

詳しい方助けて頂けないでしょうか？よろしくお願いします。

### setup.py

```
import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

# Dependencies are automatically detected, but it might need fine tuning.

includes = []


build_exe_options = {"packages": [], "excludes": [], "includes": includes, "include_files":"web"}

# GUI applications require a different base on Windows (the default is for
# a console application).
base = None
if sys.platform == "win32":
    base = "Win32GUI"

setup(  name = "YT_Download",
        version = "0.1",
        description = "YoutubeDownloader",
        options = {"build_exe": build_exe_options},
        executables = [Executable("app.py", base=base)])
```

### エラーの内容

```
running bdist_mac
running build
running build_exe
*** WARNING *** default bin include not found: libpython3.7m.dylib
creating directory build/exe.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.7
copying /Users/test/anaconda3/envs/youtube/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cx_Freeze/bases/Console -> build/exe.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.7/app
writing zip file build/exe.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.7/lib/library.zip
```

Comment: anacondaとpipを混ぜているのが原因では？ pyinstaller等での話ですが、単独で使っているようでもこんなにてこずるようですので。[Macでpyinstallerを使ってPythonコードから実行ファイルを生成した時の記録（OSError: Python library not found: libpython3.7m.dylib, .Python, libpython3.7.dylibの回避）](https://qiita.com/kanedaq/items/8bb33c135fd89991d548), [macOS: Install OpenCV 3 and Python 3.5](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/12/05/macos-install-opencv-3-and-python-3-5/) anacondaかpipか、どちらかに統一してから試してみてはどうでしょう？

Comment: 混ぜずにconda install もやってみたのですが、今度はインストールしたcx_Freezeがなくてimport出来ないというエラーで詰まりました。